# cxgrid expand blobedit pict (picture)

Tags: delphi, devexpress, delphi-xe4, tcxgrid

I have a graphic field in cxGrid (Properties = BlobEdit, BlobEditKind = bekPict,PictureClassGraphicname = TJPEGImage).I tought it was going to expand to its natural size by setting PictureAutoSize = True but it wont. I tried increasing PopUpHeight,PopUpWidth with no avail. Is there a way to make this picture show in desired proportions or at least the original size. I paste print screen images inside and if I can not see properly,what's  the use.

Comment: Having worked with a bit with DevExpress components including the grid, I have found their sample code to be of great use. Have a look in your start menu, you should find a link to them under the DevExpress folder. Be warned though: I have found in some cases that altering the sample code produces errors that prevents compilation, so it's a case of look, but only copy from the sample.

Comment: cxGrid - is grid, set of cells, it is not a component for viewing of pictures. It doesn't make sense to put any really big image in one cell of the grid, because cxGrid can scroll vertically only row by row. It means if you show big image, then height of cell (and row) will be huge and user will see kind of jumping between images instead of scrolling. If you want to show big images, i think you should consider of use another component.